# Android Layout Image Top Right Corner

Tags: android, android-layout

I am showing texts and images in a certain format and it looks like this now

[image]

Now I am trying to add another image top right that is horizontal to the header text so like this

[image]

I just can't seem to get that image in the right corner vertical to header without messing up that other text and images

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#000000"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<TextView

    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageFavourites"
    android:layout_gravity="right" />

<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#C3C3C3"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView

        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="text"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="18sp" />



</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You want that image on the action bar??

Comment: you have to make a costume toolbar then only you can add image

Comment: LOL I said nothing about a toolbar all just normal layouts

Comment: then have your Image view within Relative Layout and set android:layout_alignParentRight="true" that will do the job for you

Comment: If i use a Relative Layout the other texts and images that are below scamble out of place.

Comment: I have tried everybody's methods but everytime I change one thing another image or text pops out of place

Comment: Check my answer for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout

    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="text"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageFavourites"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout

        android:background="#C3C3C3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView

            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="text"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="text"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="text"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="18sp" />


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep those three images in `LinearLayout` and create a `RelativeLayout` as parent of the `LinearLayout` and `imageFavourites`